# create a for-loop in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have a sequence of numbers that go from 65 to 60 and decreases with 1/12 in each step.

```
seq(65, 60, (-1/12))


[1] 65.00000 64.91667 64.83333 64.75000 64.66667 64.58333 64.50000 64.41667 64.33333 64.25000 64.16667
[12] 64.08333 64.00000 63.91667 63.83333 63.75000 63.66667 63.58333 63.50000 63.41667 63.33333 63.25000
[23] 63.16667 63.08333 63.00000 62.91667 62.83333 62.75000 62.66667 62.58333 62.50000 62.41667 62.33333
[34] 62.25000 62.16667 62.08333 62.00000 61.91667 61.83333 61.75000 61.66667 61.58333 61.50000 61.41667
[45] 61.33333 61.25000 61.16667 61.08333 61.00000 60.91667 60.83333 60.75000 60.66667 60.58333 60.50000
[56] 60.41667 60.33333 60.25000 60.16667 60.08333 60.00000
```

For all these steps, I shall calculate them one by one ( they depend on each other so we have to calculate in order).

I realize that they are impossible to sit down and write out all. I started by doing so, to be able to figure out how I could create a for-loop. But they do not go well, I get the error all the time.

This is what I have managed to do in R:

```
mu10<-0.0067
mu12<-0.5
mu20<-1.03*mu10
mu21<-3
r<-log(1+0.01)
b1<-(-1500)
b2<-25000*0.15*12
c10<-45000*10
c20<-45000*10
h<-1/12

v(65)=h*(b1+mu10*c10+mu12)
w(65)=h*(b2+mu20*c20+mu21)

v(64.91667)=v(65)+h*(-r*v(65)+b1+mu10*(c10-v(65))+mu12*(w(65)-v(65)))
w(64.91667)=w(65)+h*(-r*w(65)+b2+mu20*(c20-w(65))+mu21*(v(65)-w(65)))

v(64.83333)=v(64.91667)+h*(-r*v(64.91667)+b1+mu10*(c10-v(64.91667))+mu12*(w(64.91667)-v(64.91667)))
w(64.83333)=w(64.91667)+h*(-r*w(64.91667)+b1+mu10*(c10-w(64.91667))+mu12*(v(64.91667)-w(64.91667)))
.
.
.
.
.
v(60)=....
w(60)=....
```

V and W are interrelated .Each "new" equation on the left hand side is decreasing by h=-1/12. 
To clarify a bit what I am doing in each step above , I have written out my h instead. But they are exactly the same, only printed with h instead.

```
v(65)=h*(b1+mu10*c10+mu12)
w(65)=h*(b2+mu20*c20+mu21)

v(65-h)=v(64.91667+h)+h*(-r*v(64.91667+h)+b1+mu10*(c10-v(64.91667+h))+mu12*(w(64.91667+h)-v(64.91667+h)))
w(65-h)=w(64.91667+h)+h*(-r*w(64.91667+h)+b1+mu10*(c10-w(64.91667+h))+mu12*(v(64.91667+h)-w(64.91667+h)))


v(64.91667-h)=v(64.83333+h)+h*(-r*v(64.83333+h)+b1+mu10*(c10-v(64.83333+h))+mu12*(w(64.83333+h)-v(64.83333+h)))
w(64.91667-h)=w(64.83333+h)+h*(-r*w(64.83333+h)+b1+mu10*(c10-w(64.83333+h))+mu12*(v(64.83333+h)-w(64.83333+h)))
.
.
.
.
.
v(60)=....
w(60)=....
```

**So what I need help with is: To create a for-loop, so I do not have to sit and figure out each step as they are very many. I want to use the for-loop so I can find out what `v(60)` and `w(60)` is.**

Comment: Above you are writing, e.g. `v[64.91667]`, `w[64.91667]`. I take it that `v` and `w` are **not** vectors - i.e. that is *not* supposed to represent the 64.91667th element of `v` and `w`, respectively, but rather is functional notation (`v(64.91667)`, `w(64.91667)`)?

Comment: Excuse the confusion. They are functions. Has now changed from [] to ( ). @nrussell

Comment: You can't use funcion calls on the left side of an assignment. Does the error messages not tell that? (There are a few exceptions, e.g. `names(...) <- ...` )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
a <- seq(65, 60, (-1/12))
v <- a*0
w <- a*0
mu10<-0.0067
mu12<-0.5
mu20<-1.03*mu10
mu21<-3
r<-log(1+0.01)
b1<-(-1500)
b2<-25000*0.15*12
c10<-45000*10
c20<-45000*10
h<-1/12

v[1] <- h*(b1+mu10*c10+mu12)
w[1] <- h*(b1+mu10*c10+mu12)

for (k in 2:length(a)){
  v[k] <- v[k-1]+h*(-r*v[k-1]+b1+mu10*(c10-v[k-1])+mu12*(w[k-1]-v[k-1]))
  w[k] <- w[k-1]+h*(-r*w[k-1]+b2+mu20*(c20-w[k-1])+mu21*(v[k-1]-w[k-1]))
}
```